# How to add one list's items to another list, one by one?

Tags: python, list, loops, append, extend

I have a csv file with some contents as shown below:

```
name,x,y
N1,30.2356,12.5263
N2,30.2452,12.5300
```

...and it goes on.

This is what I tried, I called them from .csv and seperately added to different lists.

```
import csv

nn = []
xkoor = []
ykoor = []
coord = []
with open('C:/Users/Mert/Desktop/py/transformation/1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        nn.append(row[0].split(','))
        xkoor.append(row[1].split(','))
        ykoor.append(row[2].split(','))

j = 1
for i in range(len(xkoor)):
    for j in range(len(ykoor)):
```

I'm trying to make a list as:

```
coord = [30.2356,12.5263],[30.2452,12.5300],....
```

and I couldn't understand how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csv-reader should split rows for you by commas on default:

```py
import csv

with open('somefile.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

# outputs
['name', 'x', 'y']
['N1', '30.2356', '12.5263']
['N2', '30.2452', '12.5300 ']
```

With this in mind, if you are just looking to loop over coords, you can use unpacking to get your `x` and `y`, then build your list by appending tuples:

```py
import csv

coords = []

with open('somefile.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    next(reader) # skips the headers
    for row in reader:
        name, x, y = row
        coords.append((float(x), float(y)))

# then you can iterate over that list like so
for x, y in coords:
    # do something
```

Coords will then look like:

```
[(30.2356, 12.5263), (30.2452, 12.53)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not split the strings by commas yourself since `csv.reader` already does it for you. Simply iterate over the `csv.reader` generator and unpack the columns as desired:

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
next(reader)
coord = [[float(x), float(y)] for _, x, y in reader]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're over-complicating things.

If all you're trying to do is create an array of coordinates containing only the X and Y values, this is how you would accomplish that:

```
import csv
coord = []
with open('C:/Users/Mert/Desktop/py/transformation/1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        rowlist = row.split(',')
        coord.append(rowlist[1:3])
print(coord)
```

All you need to do is extract a subset on a per-row basis, and append it to your coord array. No need to call row split each time, or to create separate arrays for your axis.

K.I.S.S!

(Also, a word of advice - keep PII out of your questions. No need to use your whole windows file path, just indicate that it's a CSV file. I didn't need to know your name to answer the question!)

Answer (score 0):

Why not pandas?!

- read_csv will ready your file and convert as a dataframe
- iterate on rows and access columns x and y
- combine into a list of list

and it is easier to use

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', header=0)
    [[r.x, r.y] for _, r in df.iterrows()]
```

Result:

```
[[30.2356, 12.5263], [30.2452, 12.53]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it something like this:

```
import csv

# coordinates as strings 
with open('some.csv', 'r') as f:
    cord = [a for _, *a in csv.reader(f)]

# coordinates as floats
with open('some.csv', 'r') as f:
    cord = [[float(x), float(y)] for _, x, y in csv.reader(f)]

[print(xy) for xy in cord]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are into oneliners:

```
data = """name,x,y
N1,30.2356,12.5263
N2,30.2452,12.5300"""

coords = [[x,y]
          for line in data.split("\n")[1:]
          for _,x,y in [line.split(",")]]
print(coords)
```

This yields

```
[['30.2356', '12.5263'], ['30.2452', '12.5300']]
```